# docker Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp

Tags: docker, proxy, centos

I try use docker accros cntlm proxy. I have 2 VM:

1. VM cntlm gateway (CentOS)
2. VM docker (CentOS)

Before that I added proxy conf docker: [https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy:~:text=systemd/system.-,HTTP/HTTPS%20proxy%F0%9F%94%97,-The%20Docker%20daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy:%7E:text=systemd/system.-,HTTP/HTTPS%20proxy%F0%9F%94%97,-The%20Docker%20daemon)

I try use, but get error:

```
> sudo docker pull hello-world                                                                                                                                                                                   ⏎
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: read tcp ip:port->ip:3128: read: connection reset by peer
```

Before that I added proxy conf docker: [https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy:%5C~:text=systemd/system.-,HTTP/HTTPS%20proxy%F0%9F%94%97,-The%20Docker%20daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy:%5C%7E:text=systemd/system.-,HTTP/HTTPS%20proxy%F0%9F%94%97,-The%20Docker%20daemon)

I try use, but get error:

```
> sudo docker pull hello-world                                                                                                                                                                                   ⏎
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: read tcp ip:port->ip:3128: read: connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Can you connect to your proxy from the VM?

Comment: Yes, wget  work is well

Comment: I see wireshark, and my cntlm proxy send me RST packet.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, I set proxy in format https://... But cntlm does not understand this format only http://